# Nginx: Serve static folder alongside with html file

Tags: nginx

I have a file structure like this:

```
 ui
 --index.html
 --nginx.conf
 --static
   --css
   --script
```

I am able to see the index.html through this nginx.conf:

```
upstream api {
      server api:8060;
    }

    server {
        listen 100;
        charset utf-8;
        server_name  localhost;

        root   /usr/share/nginx/html/ai;
        index  index.html index.htm;
        include /etc/nginx/extra-conf.d/*.conf;
 


        gzip on;
        gzip_types text/css text/javascript application/x-javascript application/json;

        # backend urls
        location /ai/ {
        try_files $uri /index.html;



        # static files
        location /static/ {
            proxy_pass http://api;
        }

        }
```

The issue is that I have the `static` folder which has some files which is required for loading index.html completely but I am not able to have access to them and they won't load in my ui and I receive errors like this:

```
        GET http://localhost:8080/static/css/css/common-page.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
```

How can I attach `static` folder to my ui?

Comment: In case you want to load static files from `/static` why the proxy pass directive here ?

Comment: @MauriceMeyer do you mean this?        ` # static files
        location /static/ {
            proxy_pass http://api;
        }` I removed it but still unable to attach static folder for the ui.